# Add another email in GMail through SMTP server

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

I've had some luck using Postfix to relay emails sent to my server to multiple GMail accounts, but now I would like to go the other way around.

That is, use the gmail `"Add another email as your own"` SMTP configuration feature in order to allow me and another user to send emails under the domain associated with the server. I haven't really found a clear answer on how to do this or what the issues with this setup are. Would appreciate any pointers on this.

I am using Debian hosted on Digital Ocean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use gmail as a relay for postfix with multiple users the basics are as follows:

Add the following lines to main.cf (all files in /etc/postfix)

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relay
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Create a file sasl_passwd with the following contents:

```
user1@example.com    user1@gmail.com:password1
user2@example.com    user2@gmail.com:password2
```

Create a file sender_relay

```
user1@example.com  [smtp.gmail.com]:587
user2@example.com  [smtp.gmail.com]:587
```

Full details are at [Postix SASL README](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl)
There is a recipe to generate a self signed certificate for smtp_tls_CA_file at [Postfix TLS README](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html)